# EXCEL 2016 Power query Errror when CLOSE AND LOAD

Tags: excel, powerquery

In Excel 2016 when I create a simple query  ( select * from table1) in  power query editor it runs Ok and load all the data.

But when select close and load only get a few rows and get an error:

"Error initialization  data source"

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you see only few rows in preview, and error is encountered later on.
Try browsing a hundred of rows, or more. If you won't get that error, you need to post more details - what datasource do you query, for example.